# Is the 'au' phoneme on the decline?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I live in the midwest, grew up in Chicago. Here, altho there is usually a clear distinction between au like in 'auditorium' and o like in 'on', the 2 are often used interchangeably in ordinary conversation, mostly tending to o in place of au. This seems to be true in the national media also.

Some people actual pronounce all such words with a vowel that's between those 2, and if you listen carefully, most people also use this middle ground sound in most of the words with either.

I paid particular attention to this during the 90's while refining Nooalf. It seemed to hold true thru the aughts, but since I haven't been paying such close attention till now, I am not sure if it's actually spreading to other dialectical regions or if my very limited samples are evidence of a general trend.

If you want to look into this, pay particular attention to people saying 'dawn' and 'Don'.  I often watch the ABC insomniac news which is from New York.

Comment: What you say is correct; it's a fairly well-known phenomenon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_low_back_vowels#Cot.E2.80.93caught_merger. What is the question, though? It seems you are already aware of the existence of this merger. Generally, mergers of two sounds don't reverse themselves. But it's hard to predict if a merger will spread to all speakers or not.

Comment: I guess you want to know if the spread of the merger  in recent years has been measured? People do do dialect surveys that might provide info for an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The Wiki article explained it very well. Good to know It's not just my own perception.

Comment: Is your **audio** working? Is there any other way to pronounce it? Is he autocratic? Is this automation.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [**cot-caught merger.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot%E2%80%93caught_merger) As Wikipedia states:

> Even without taking into account the mobility of the American population, the distribution of the merger is still complex; there are pockets of speakers with the merger in areas that lack it, and vice versa. There are areas where the merger has only partially occurred, or is in a state of transition.